# Multiple databases vs a single database

Tags: database, database-design

I'm looking at an existing site and they are using separate databases. The databases seem to be setup in the following manner:

- general types (user_type, language, age, etc)
- member data (registration information & login)
- site configuration

Personally, I would put everything into 1 database. To me this would make it easier than almost always having to put the database name in front of every table.

I can see from a security perspective ensuring that people cannot access the wrong data by accident, but on this site there are going to be admins (about 10% of the users on the site) that will need to access all the databases, doing cross database searches.

What could be the reasons for doing separate databases? (The site is in PHP & MySQL.)

**Edit:** The names of the db are:

- `sitename` (the actual site name) (general types)
- `member` (member data)
- `siteconfig` (site configuration)

Comment: Yeah, this is low-level crazy.  More work for the programmers, but the payoff is more work for the programmers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Purely speculation on what was in the minds of the creators:

Maybe a difference in the volitilaty of the data, so that there could be a different backup/replication strategy for the different physical dbs?

Maybe an idea that say, "general types" could be shared across multiple applications but the "site configuration", for example, would be specific to just one application?

Maybe an idea that the different databases could be put on different pieces of hardware that have different performance characteristics, like their RAID configuration.   Data that is read a lot but not updated versus data that is updated a lot.

Again, pure speculation...

@Darryl - my answer is more archeology than technology.  I'm not saying I buy any of it.  I'm just trying to step into the mindset of the ancestors...

Answer (score 1):

Also pure speculation: Perhaps it was an architectural decision to support separation of concerns.

Comment: Not up on the termonology...can you explain concerns?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong here, but in general it means you separate the design and work, and hand it off to a different developer, to find the best solution for that problem instead of a generic solution for everything.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a reason to create multiple databases for the information you listed, especially if that data needs to be cross-linked.  It sounds more like someone didn't know how to use permissions so instead of granting access to tables they just created new databases. Just an opinion, but cutting things down to just one database would probably be an improvement.

Comment: It's amazing what ignorance can produce.  I work with a database that has no primary keys at all, a situation which came about because the original developers didn't know how to create views.

Comment: @MusiGenesis I missed this. :( What is the correlation between having no primary keys and creating views?

Answer (score 0):

We face such a question in android especially *(for reference)*

**Working with Databases in Multi module app in Android**

When we modularise an app, we face problem about where to keep our database. While there is no specific correct method to do so, one of the implementation is using a single common database for the entire app. The other is creating a database for core common functionality and then separate for feature modules.

**Pros / cons of a Single Database**

*Pros:*

1. Easy to maintain database connection since we need to open one db connection only.
2. Easy to share tables.

*Cons:*

1. No isolation between modules therefore we need to rename these tables to not conflict across modules.
2. No specific entities are in shared domain. We need to put all entities and daos into core module that ships with app.

**Pros / cons of a One Database / Module**

*Pros:*

1. Perfect isolation between modules.

*Cons:*

1. DB connection maintenance. If we want to write a queries across modules, it is complex.

Answer (score -1):

If there were a good reason for breaking up a database into a bunch of smaller ones like this, the databases would probably have names like "hadronsupercolliderrawdata" and "googlebackup_2008".  Names like "generaltypes" and "memberdata" suggest they were just overwhelmed by stupidity.

Comment: is there a reason you feel the need to insult somebody's intelligence based on their application design? Perhaps they were (and likely) novice programmers at start of a project/company. Saying somebody is "stupid" because of poor design tends to make you look that way.

Comment: @JM4: saying that I'm stupid because I called somebody else stupid is sort of, well, stupid, if you don't mind my saying so. Saying that I'm a dick because I called somebody else stupid would be completely accurate, and also not stupid. As far as the meat of your comment, of course they were novice programmers at the start of a project - that's where most bad code comes from.